# Can Minetest for Ubuntu 19.10 be installed on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, games

I downloaded a game, Minetest, a while ago, that started on Ubuntu 16.04. New updates have been created, but the latest Minetest 5.0.0 update is said to work on Ubuntu 19.10. I really enjoy playing Minetest, and to play online you need that update absolutely.

Is the game still runnable, and if yes, are there any risks for my computer?

Comment: 19.10 is still in beta stage. Compatibility depends on the dependencies. If the dependency of the "game" is satisfiable on 19.10 as well as 18.04, you can run that but if not, you should be brave enough to satisfy the dependency without breaking the system.

Comment: Crap sorry i forgot the name. It's Minetest 5.0.0 . Excuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download minetest for Ubuntu 19.10 and libncursesw6, libtinfo6 and libleveldb1d (the only missing dependencies) and it can be installed in 18.04. If it is installed correctly, there are no risks for your computer in running Minetest for Ubuntu 19.10 in 18.04.

Download links to minetest, libncursesw6, libtinfo6 and libleveldb1:

- [minetest](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/minetest/download)
- [libncursesw6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/libncursesw6/download)
- [libtinfo6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/libtinfo6/download)
- [libleveldb1d](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/libleveldb1d/download)

Open the terminal, change directories using `cd` to the directory containing the 4 files that you downloaded, and type:

```
sudo apt install ./libleveldb1d_1.20-2.1_amd64.deb ./libncursesw6_6.1+20181013-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./libtinfo6_6.1+20181013-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./minetest_5.0.1+repack-2_amd64.deb
```